# Find out what process is using my HDD

Tags: hard-drive

I know it's the spotlight indexing process, but it's been killing my HDD for the last few days and will not stop. The CPU usage is rather low but `fs_usage` shows that the mds process is doing something the whole time.

I'v tried force quitting it with `kill -9` but it will just auto re-spawn and keep killing my HDD.

I'v added all my HDDs into the Spotlight privacy list as well as disabling indexing `sudo mdutil -a -i off`
I'v done several restarts but it keeps on going.

Any ideas on how to stop it from opening and running?

**Update:**

I Managed to stop mds by the following command:

`sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library//LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.*`

But after a restart my HDD is still writing ~6MB/s and reading ~500KB/s
Any ideas how to find out which process is consuming my HDD? It makes my computer incredible slow.

**Update 2:**

It only does 3MB/s write now that I have left the computer alone for a while.

**Update 3:**

It stopped just now for about 5 seconds, then started writing again.
I was doing nothing different.

Here is a screenshot of the usage:

[image: hdd usage]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "killing my HDD?"

Comment: You've got to nuke all the existing indexes, and just let Spotlight run once through completely. Also, 6MB/s is not a lot. On average, a hard drive will range from 30MB/s to over 80MB/s on higher-end hardware. Bite the bullet and let it run.

Comment: @DustinStalin Just that it uses the HDD so intense that in turn the OS can't do it's day to day tasks. Like run my apps at any decent speed.

Comment: It's still doing a spotlight index?

Comment: @RandolphWest I know it's not, but it must be writing to some odd places to cause such a slow down for 6MB/s, though now it's down to 3MB/s and my computer is still just as slow. mds isn't running anymore so it can't be spotlight.

Comment: @DustinStalin No. I can't find any mds process so I would think not.

Comment: Just a basic suggestion, but have you tried browsing through Activity Monitor?

Comment: I was hoping that there would be an app that would tell you which process is reading/writing... I will have a look though Activity Monitor.

Comment: It appears to be postfix. Pretty sure this came with Lion Server, as I installed that recently and did try using it's Mail server. I did disable Lion Server as per Apple instructions but obviously that doesn't get rid of all the little programs it was using.

Comment: Temporary fix for other users ` sudo kill -9 $(ps -u _postfix -o "pid=")` I'm working on a proper fix, as currently postfix will auto re-start it's processes and in turn starting writing to the HDD again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running the `fs_usage` in Terminal (must be run as root):

```
sudo fs_usage
```

This will start spitting out details of all your disk access right there in the Terminal window. It might go by quickly, but you should at least be able to see the app names accessing the disk.

More info and options for the fs_usage command [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html).

Answer (score 3):

[fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) is an awesome frontend to the information that fs_usage provides, and enables a better understanding of filesystem activity much quicker than at the command line.